# How to retrieve user editable table field value in django

Tags: django

```
models.py

class Invoice(models.Model):
        Invoice_No=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        Invoice_Date_Of_Issue=models.DateField(null=False)
        Status=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
        Discount=models.IntegerField(null=True)


class Invoice_Details(models.Model):
        Invoice_Line_No=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        Invoice_No=models.ForeignKey('Invoice',null=False)
        Details=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
        Quantity=models.IntegerField(null=False)
        Cost=models.FloatField(null=False)

view.py

def index(request):
    data=Invoice.objects.all()
    form=InvoiceForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it=form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()
        data1=Invoice.objects.all()[::-1][:1]

    return     render_to_response('invoice.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
return    render_to_response('invoice.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(re  quest))

invoice.html
<form action="" method="post">
<div style="float:right">
</div>
{{ form.as_p }}{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="">

<table id ="myTable">

<h3 align = "center"> Enter Invoice Details Below</h3>


    <th>Invoice_Line_No</th>
    <th>Invoice_No</th>
    <th>Details</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Cost</th>

<tr>
    <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable></div></td>

    </tr>


</table>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add new row</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable></div>";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable></div>";
    cell3.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable></div>";
    cell4.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable></div>";
    cell5.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable></div>";

}
</script>
```

Within my Invoice addform page..on submit.. i have to create an editable       table for the user to insert Invoice_details records. For the same Invoice_No there can be multiple Invoice_details.Using Javascript i am able to create new rows whenever user clicks Add new row button. But i am not aware how to retrieve the data from invoice.html (editable table fields) to the view and save it in database.

Can anyone help me out with this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make it clean and the Django way, try formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Thank you for the information.